# Getting soft, but not sweet onions

Tags: onions

Is there a way to cook onion soft, but  have them retain the nutty flavor? Every time I cook them over low heat, they turn soft after a while. I want them to loose their crunchy texture, but not the nutty flavor.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Onions are not normally described as "nutty", so it's hard to answer your question.  What particular flavor of onions are you trying to describe?

Comment: It's also confusing because you say "not have them **retain** the nutty flavor" and then you also say "not loose(sic) the nutty flavor"  so you don't want it, or you do...? Please [edit] to clarify. If you're objecting to caramelization (which "not sweet" implies) try even lower temperatures.

Comment: You can saute them on medium high heat for a few minutes and stir. They won't burn if you stir frequently but you'll need to watch them carefully so as not to turn completely soft.

Comment: If you do want them completely soft and not caramelized, you can add a pinch of baking soda, which will break down the onions and turn them brown without caramelizing and turning sweet.